# Javascript - hide a Div

Tags: javascript

Sorry, I am new to stack overflow so hope I am doing this correctly.

I have the following code:

```
{
  if (session.findById("T1").text == "") {
    document.getElementById("W1").style.display = 'none';
  } else {
    document.getElementById("W1").style.display = 'inline';
  }
}
```

Basically it is saying if `T1` is blank, then `W1` should not show. If `T1` is not blank, `W1` will show.

I can't get it working and then tried this by itself:

```
document.getElementById("W1").style.display = 'none';
```

What happens is the item quickly disappears (flashes) but then comes back again. So it's kind of working but I want it to stay permanently hidden. Unless of course `T1` contains text and then it should reappear.

How can I resolve?

Thanks!!

Comment: What is `findById()` method? No such method exists in native JavaScript.

Comment: Have you tried logging `.text`? I guess it should be `.innerText` or `.textContent` or if its an input, then `.value`. Also try using `.trim` to remove unwanted spaces

Comment: Agree with Muhammad, problem near session.findById("T1")

Comment: Does any other code set the display of the element? It would only flicker if the style is being overwritten.

Comment: @MuhammadUsman The `findById()` function isn't relevant, since the OP can reproduce the problem even when it's not there.

Comment: @Rajesh You're right, all of my idea were garbage, ok? so i will delete them. ok? wasting time

Answer (score 1):

hey look at my example

```js
function isEmpty() {
  var sample = document.getElementById("sample");
  var div = document.getElementById("divko");
  if (sample.value.trim() == "") {
    div.setAttribute("style", "display:none;");
  } else {
    div.removeAttribute("style");
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="sample" name="sample" onkeyup="isEmpty()">
<div id="divko" style="display:none;">Sample</div>
```

Comment: Note, its not wise to remove attribute `style`. Also its better to use `element.style.display= ...`. And last thing if you enter space, it will show the div. I'm not sure if OP is looking for it but you should consider both options.

Comment: just add a trim function for a space value

Answer (score 0):

you can use following hide option

```
document.getElementById("W1").style.display = 'block';
```